# How can I erase everything when installing elementary OS?

Tags: system-installation, disk-management

I cannot access the desktop on my Windows XP installation. It won't even start on secure mode. I just want to know so I can install a Linux distro.

Comment: If you don't have access to windows ask in https://superuser.com/ . If you want to replace with elementary you will loss important data, are you sure to replace?

Comment: Yes, I don't care about the info in it anymore. I just want to get it wiped out so I can install a Native Install for a Linux Distro.

Comment: `As you're a reputation 1 user: If the below answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

When installing elementary there is a <kbd>use entire hard drive</kbd> or <kbd>erase disk and install elementary os</kbd> option. This will destroy both your Windows installation and **any files you have saved there**.

Comment: Sorry but my problem is not solved. Windows-XP won't even load my Desktop. I just need a way to erase my hard disk so I can install Linux from an external Hard Disk. ( am I being clear? )

Comment: You can erase your hard drive when you install elementary, there is no need to do it before hand.

Answer (score 0):

If the above suggestions did not answer your question to your satisfaction ... try using a mini distro JUST used for partitioning a disk ... maybe try using gParted Live (I have no affiliation with it).
I know this solution doesn't use Elementary ... but perhaps this will let you do what you want ... in case your question wasn't stated specific enough for us to offer another solution.